# How can i use the value which i got from a form as an variable in my dao class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jdbc

I am trying to create a page on which i will type the interest like java and then i will fetch all the rows from database which has interest as java so i have created this form element

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="interest"><br>
```

This is my mapping in my controller

```
@ModelAttribute("courses")
    public Map<String, String> getCourseList() throws SQLException, IOException {

        return (new ServiceImpl()).getCourseList();
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="showCourses", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView showCourses(@RequestParam("interest") String interest) {
        ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView();
        mv.addObject("interest",interest);
        mv.setViewName("showCourses");
        return mv;
    }
```

I am fetching all the courses from the database but in my daoimpl class

```
public Map<String, String> courseList() throws SQLException, IOException {
        connect();
        Map<String, String> courseList = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String sql = "SELECT * from course;";
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            courseList.put(resultSet.getString("CourseName"), resultSet.getString("CourseName"));
        }
        return courseList;
    }
```

in this courseList method i want to use the interest so that i can only fetch the courses which are of specific interest and show them on my jsp how can i use the interest in my daoImpl class?

Comment: Dont understand what the problem is. But first, I assume `ServiceImpl` is a Spring bean and should not be instantiated directly. Instead autowire the bean. Second, to use a query parameter in you dao, just provide as method parameter

Comment: Ok i will make ServiceImpl as a Bean and autowire it but how can i pass the interest which i requested in my controller to dao?

Comment: Just as a method parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look in below code snippet.

you have already implemented dao just need little modification on that method :-

```
public Map<String, String> getCourseList(String subjectInterest) {
     connect();
     Map<String, String> courseList = new HashMap<String, String>();
     String sql = "SELECT * from course where subInterest = ?";
     statement.setString(1,subjectInterest);
     resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
     while (resultSet.next()) {
        courseList.put(resultSet.getString("CourseName"), resultSet.getString("CourseName"));
     }
     return courseList;
}
```

Along with this you need to implement one service class from where you can call your dao method for fetching the course details like below :-

```
@Service
public class CourseService {
    @Autowired
    private CourseDAO courseDao;

    public Map<String, String> getCourseList(String subjectInterest) throws SQLException, IOException {
        return courseDao.getCourseList(subjectInterest);
    }
}
```

Post this in your controller need to change little bit something like below :-

```
@Controller
public class CourseController {

    @Autowired
    private CourseService courseService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/showCourses", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String showCourses(@RequestParam("interest") String interest, Model model) throws SQLException, IOException {
        model.addAttribute("interest", interest);
        Map<String, String> courseList = courseService.getCourseList(interest);
        model.addAttribute("courseList", courseList);
        return "showCourses";
    }

}
```

And finally you need to loop **courseList** attribute in your showCourses.jsp, So you will be able to show courses based on interest.